# how to subset columns of data frame in r

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have lots of data frame like the one below. I need to find the Total in last sample just before weight value is zero. here for example in the sample of 7 I need to find the weight that is 6.

```
Sample Weight Total
1       2     0
2       3     0 
3       7     0
4       5     4
5       4     3
6       3     8
7       6     12
8       0     11
9       0     8
10      0     9
```

Here is what i have tried:

```
New.DF <- DF$Total [ Weight > 0, Sample=max]
```

Comment: Can u show the expected otuput

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to extract the column

```
 with(DF, max(Sample[Weight!=0]))
 #[1] 7
```

---

Or may be

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[Weight!=0, .SD[.N] ,.(grp = rleid(Weight==0))]
#      grp Sample Total
#1:     1      7    12
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, i tried first but why these two give me different answer?b <-with(df, max(Sample[EZ!=0]))

c<- df$Sample[ with(df, max(Sample[EZ!=0]))]

Comment: @Mori It is because you are subsetting the `Sample` and then use it as an index in the 2nd case, which is not right.  INstead you may need `i1 <- with(df, Sample == max(Sample[EZ !=0]))` and use that to subset